# Woocommerce checkout on the home page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I have WP 3.9.1 and WC 2.1.12 installed.

There are 2 pages: home page and checkout page for redirect from PayPal and place order.

I have checkout in the modal window on the home page. So user choose
 attributes for product variation, product adds to the cart with Ajax.
 So if i open checkout, everything looks fine, but countries selection,
 shipping and tax options don't work, in the same time on the checkout
 page I don't have such problems. I've noticed that I should add
 `wc-checkout` scripts to the front page, so I load them with this
 function

```
wp_enqueue_script('wc-checkout', plugins_url() . '/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/checkout.min.js', array('jquery', 'woocommerce', 'wc-country-select', 'wc-address-i18n', ), null, true);
```

and it works, but only after reloading the page. Thanks for any advise.